# Disable Auto Grid Resizing in XAML Designer using VS 2019

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

This very frustrating problem keeps happening (now in vs 2019 and before in vs 2017) and after finding zilch looking through the XAML options and searching for similar issues I was hoping someone can help with this:

Selecting elements in the designer (particularly grid elements) will sometimes alter the * grid definitions to crazy values that will LOOK the same visually but then when I look at them markup at some point the ratios have gotten HUGE or even it will add extra rows/cols and then automatically change the spans of what is actually there its nerveracking!

Any ideas what this awful setting is or what I'm clicking to make this happen?

For example it will change this:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
```

To this:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="37*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="513*" />
```

And it never affects the view in the designer just the markup. That's as much explanation I can give offhand, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of rows to columns in a Grid is very precise. For your first ColumnDefinition, means dividing the width of the whole Grid into ten parts,the first column is 20% of the width of Grid, second is 10%,third is 30%.This is desgined by your need.

When you do a little modifity in the designer, all column widths maybe distributed proportionally if you choose Star for the ColumnDefinition in the designer as the below picture shown:
[image]

Comment: I understand how the star ratios work but I am not editing them in the designer and left to assume it happens because I occasionally click elements, not drag or move gizmos to move the caret in the editor (in split view) to that element so it's a strange reaction to happen, especially when it automatically adds new columns and then spans to compensate for them so everything still looks the same! Pretty bizarre - I am on a laptop with a touch pad so maybe its multi-finger thing? I don't know but hopefully you see more clearly my specific quandary...

Comment: What element did you click?How do you add the column and sapn them?I need more details to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Really that is the question lol, is how AM I producing the columns and spans! Its when i click an element in the designer to move the editors caret their and I must be clicking the edges of a grid cell or the little chain link adornment but I'm not dragging it anywhere, its like it does some auto adjustment to the proportions to retain the layout but changes the proportions I coded in really weird ways. Its something you would definitely notice if you are setting the markup and not moving the spinners in the designer.

Comment: My 'solution' is to just stop clicking in the designer and find things using the Document Outline view...

Comment: Could you think about Blend for Visual Studio to design your xaml?

Comment: Blend has the same issue which I've concluded is due to me using a trackpad (MacBookPro) where the Designer is misinterpreting my clicks (to move the XAML editor to the clicked element) as drags which alters grid definitions in the weird ways I tried to describe. My solution is just to stop using the design view :p Thanks for trying to help though!